# No data in Listview with contentprovider

Tags: java, android, listview, android-contentprovider

I'm working on a class project in Java, exploring the use of the `ContentProvider` class for moving data between apps.  We're making a basic CRUD app, with `SQLite` storage and a ContentProvider to move data to a second app.  My debugging shows that my SQLite inserts seem to be working and building my database, but my `ListView` will not populate.  It gives a spinning loading ring forever, which is not an issue I usually see with ListView.  I've double- and tripple- checked that the adapter is in place, and I use a part of my `loadData()` method to create a list of item objects from the database which I can't find a problem with.  I'm not sure where else the issue could be coming from.

MainActivity:

```
    public static DatabaseHelper helper;
    public static ItemProvider provider;
    static Button addNew;
    public static final int NEXT_REQUESTCODE = 1;
    static ListFragment frag;
    static ArrayList<ItemObject> items = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        provider = new ItemProvider(helper);
        FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();
        final Context context = this.getApplicationContext(); //to pass as context
        frag = ListFragment.newInstance(context, items);
        frag.loadData();


        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag, ListFragment.TAG);
        addNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        addNew.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent addActivity = new Intent(context, FormActivity.class); //sets intent for addactivity
                        startActivityForResult(addActivity, NEXT_REQUESTCODE); //starts activity expecting response


                    }
                });

    }

    //handles response from addactivity
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == NEXT_REQUESTCODE) {
            Bundle result = data.getExtras();
            ItemObject placeholder = new ItemObject(result.getString("weight"), result.getInt("steps"), result.getString("date")); //builds the object to be added to the list from addactivity response
            frag.addObject(placeholder); //adds the object to the list
        }
    }

    Context getContext() {
        return this.getContext();
    }

}
```

SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_FILE = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item_table";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_table ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT, steps INTEGER, weight TEXT)";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
        super(c, DATABASE_FILE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = getWritableDatabase();
      //  db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


        //db.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE, factory);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void addItem(ContentValues v)
    {

    }
}
```

ListFragment class

```
    public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = "ListFragment.TAG";
    public static ArrayList<ItemObject> items = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    static ListView itemList;
    static ItemAdapter adapter;
    static int selectedPosition;
    public static final int NEXT_REQUESTCODE = 2;
    static Context context;
    static ArrayList<ItemObject> placeholder;
    static MainActivity activity;
    static  Uri uri = Uri.EMPTY;

    //constructor
    public static ListFragment newInstance(Context _context, ArrayList<ItemObject> _items) {
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_layout, parent, false);
        //create and attach custom adapter
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        context = activity.getContext();
        itemList = (ListView) theView.findViewById(R.id.itemList);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(context, items);
        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
                selectedPosition = position;
                openView(items.get(position));
            }
        });
        loadData();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return theView;
    }

    //function for opening the "View details" view
    public void openView(ItemObject selected) {
        Intent detailActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
        detailActivity.putExtra("weight", selected.getWeight());
        detailActivity.putExtra("steps", selected.getSteps());
        detailActivity.putExtra("date", selected.getDate());
        detailActivity.putExtra("position", selectedPosition);
        startActivityForResult(detailActivity, NEXT_REQUESTCODE);

    }


    public void saveItem(ItemObject _item) {
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put("weight", _item.getWeight());
        v.put("steps", _item.getSteps());
        v.put("date", _item.getDate());
        activity.provider.insert(uri, v);
        loadData();


    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void loadData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"weight","steps","date"};
        Uri destination = Uri.parse(Environment.getDataDirectory().toString()+"/data/ContentProviderApp/database.db");
        Cursor c = activity.provider.query(destination, columns, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            ArrayList<ItemObject> placeholder = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
            for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
            {
                int x = c.getCount();
                ItemObject newItem = new ItemObject(c.getString(3),c.getInt(2), c.getString(1));
                placeholder.add(newItem);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            items = placeholder;

        }

    }

    public void deleteData() {
    }

    public void updateData() {
    }


    //handles a delete request from "view" activity
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == NEXT_REQUESTCODE) {
            Bundle result = data.getExtras();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }



    //Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).

    public ListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    //adds an object passed in from the activity
    public void addObject(ItemObject _item) {
        saveItem(_item);
        //items.add(_item);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //saveData();

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            //  mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        //  mListener = null;
    }
}
```

ContentProvider class

```
 public class ItemProvider extends ContentProvider {
    DatabaseHelper helper;
    public ItemProvider() {


    }
    public ItemProvider(DatabaseHelper _helper) {
        helper = _helper;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        return helper.db.query("item_table", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        helper.db.insert("item_table", null, values);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        helper.db.delete("item_table", selection, selectionArgs);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        helper.db.update("item_table", values, selection, selectionArgs);
        return 0;
    }
}

ItemAdapter class

    public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private static final long ID_CONSTANT = 0x666666L;
    private ArrayList<ItemObject> items;
    public ItemAdapter()
    {

    }
    public ItemAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<ItemObject> _items)
    {
        context = _context;
        items = _items;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {return items.size();}
    @Override
    public ItemObject getItem(int _position) {return items.get(_position);}
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int _position) { return ID_CONSTANT + _position;}
    @Override
    public View getView (int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent) {
        if(_convertView == null) {
            _convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, _parent, false);
        }
        ItemObject item = getItem(_position);
        TextView text = (TextView) _convertView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        text.setText(item.getWeight().toString());
        text = (TextView) _convertView.findViewById(R.id.steps);
        text.setText(Integer.toString(item.getSteps()));
        text = (TextView) _convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        text.setText(item.getDate().toString());
        return _convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: why dont you use a `CursorLoader` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the loadData method:

```
items = placeholder;
```

It should be `items.addAll(placeholder)`.
Did you get a chance to test this?

Answer (score 0):

In **loadData()** after the line **item = placeholder** add **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**.